# Notify ActiveX that <object> has been removed from DOM

Tags: activex, firebreath

This is a bit necroposting but I'm out of luck here.

How do I get notified in my ActiveX COM that  node has been removed from the DOM through `parent.innerHTML = ''` or `parent.removeChild(activeXID)`

[FireBreath](http://firebreath) seems to be doing it somehow

Answer (score 0):

FireBreath doesn't really support being removed and added again, but I think it is either with InPlaceDeactivate or SetClientSite somehow; you'd just have to set some breakpoints and play with it.  The file you need in FireBreath is [FBControl.h](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ActiveXCore/FBControl.h)

Comment: Thanks, Richard, we'll dig in. Overall problem is that our plugin isn't always cleared even after f5. Sometimes destructor is called and some times not, usually when browser has a lot of work to do

Comment: The most common reason I've seen this happen is when not all reference counted objects are being released when they need to be

Comment: Hello, Richard! We've tried impementing IOleInPlaceObject (together with IUnknown and IOleObject), but the problem we have is that none of it's methods are being called on removal. In fact, none of them are being called at all (the object is safe for scripting and our custom methods work fine with JS). I suspect we didn't register them properly, but I can't find any documentation on MSDN that would match the case. Do you have any advice on this? Thank you.

Comment: Not all controls use IOleInPlaceObject -- there are other interfaces which are sometimes used instead. I forget exactly -- if I were you I'd look at FBControl.h and see what it's using that you aren't and see if it might be applicable.  It's been nearly 5 years since I worked on that code much, so I don't remember exactly